# Give text as input and reply to popup message

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium Automation and got stuck in handling a popup.

In my project, I have inbox which has all inbox messages and on selecting REPLY link a popup opens on the same page.

Where we can give text as input and reply to that message?

I am unable to handle the above scenario, can anyone help me in automating this scenario?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ocii0zouz3k6d17/Screenshot%202015-05-28%2017.55.42.png?dl=0

after clicking on message link, on the same page a popup opens with reply button
and after tapping on reply button a text field appears were we can give text as input for replying the message`

```html
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header change_popup_header">
        <div class="close" aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" style="opacity:1">
            <span class="icon_img-close m-r-xs"></span>
        </div>
        <h4 id="messagePopupTitle" class="modal-title">Message</h4>
    </div>
    <input id="modalType" type="hidden">
    <div id="messagesContentDiv" class="modal-body">
        <div id="readAndReplydiv">
            <script>
            <style>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post a sample of your code for community members to help you with.

Comment: Yes, Please post a code you have tried, then only we can help you, as it is not possible to write whole code here for your scenario.

Comment: What do you mean by you are unable to handle it? Cannot close/hit ok of the modal?